# Is there a upper bound on the length of the shortest paths by degree of vertices?

Tags: graphs

I would like to know if there is an upper bound on the length of the shortest paths between vertices on an undirected and  unweighted graph based on degree of vertices, number of vertices and number of edges. I consider the shortest paths. So path length is smaller than the number of vertices. I want to know if I can get a better bound with the information of degrees of vertices.

Specifically I have a graph where degree of each vertex is either 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Paths and cycles have low degrees, so I don't think you can get a meaningful bound.

Comment: I edited the question. I want to consider only the shortest paths between vertices.

Comment: Same example still works.

Comment: What do you mean by degrees of paths and cycles?

Comment: I mean that vertices in paths and cycles have very low degrees (1 and 2), as well as only few edges, and yet their diameter is large.

Comment: Also, a trivial upper bound on the diameter is the number of edges. It's just that bounding the degrees doesn't help beyond that.